# Android and .properties file

Tags: android, properties, assets

I need a .properties file for my android application. I put it into my assets folder without thinking about the consequences. But I have to edit my .properties file during runtime, so let's say I want to add some values to it. But I've come so far that I must admit: I cannot write to assets.

Where do I put my .properties file now? Thanks for your help!

Comment: It ain't pretty much clear... Are you talking about SharedPreferences?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put your properties into your application folder. well, actually, the best way is to put your properties into the `SharedPreferences`, but the folder would work as well.

when your application starts, it should check if the file in the application folder exists (or the `SharedPreferences` are present) and then load the defaults from `assets/.properties` or use the current values from the file or `SharedPreferences`. after that, just ignore `assets/.properties` and use the current values from file or `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: SharedPreferences seems a good way to go. But I have one problem. I am working with eclipse: Where do I put my sharedPreferences.xml file?

Comment: @ZerO when you access the `SharedPreferences` you may provide default values, that could be read from the .xml file you provide or from the actual .java code -- it's your choice.